# Packaging web worker source for use with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, web-worker

I am implementing a feature in our Ember app with web workers, and am having trouble figuring out how to package the worker source.

My first approach was to place `worker.js` into the `assets` directory, but in our configuration, assets are served from a different server in production, and we get the error:

> `Failed to construct Worker: Script at https://static-assets.foo.com cannot be accessed from origin https://app.foo.com`

I tried futzing with `document.domain` (changing it to `foo.com`), but the error persists.

I wondered if I could modify `ember-cli-build.js` (aka `Brocfile.js`) to create another JS bundle in addition to `app.js` and `vendor.js` (say, `worker.js`), which would be deployed in the same location as those, and could be brought in with a `<script>` tag in `index.html`. However, I'm unable to figure out how to do that, either due to the `app.js/vendor.js` logic being burnt into `ember-cli`, or my lack of knowledge of Broccoli.

So next I considered creating the worker from a blob. The question is where to store the source for the blob. I considered placing the source for the blob inside a non-standard `<script>` tag in `index.html`, from where I could retrieve it and create the blob. I don't want to insert the worker source directly into `index.html`, though, so I thought to use `broccoli-replace`, but the worker source is written in ES6 and needs transpilation. I considered using an ember add-on which allows you to insert things into `index.html` using `{{content-for}}`, but that requires me to specify the text to be inserted, and I don't know where to get it from, and the transpilation problem remains.

I then considered some very klujy solutions such as wrapping the worker source in a function, and then stringifying the function and extracting the body (between `{}`) at run-time. That works, but the stench is a bit overwhelming, and I cannot use any ES6 constructs such as spread operators or array destructuring that cause Babel to invoke its little run-time utilities like `_toConsumableArray`.

Any reasonable solutions, or ways to make any of the above approaches work?

Comment: What about setting cors to allow script from `app.foo.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Broccoli is fancy. You will need [Funnel](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-funnel) and [MergeTrees](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-merge-trees).

Basically in your `ember-cli-build.js` you would have to return your own tree instead of `app.toTree()`. So you can do something like this:

```
let workers = new Funnel('app/workers', {
    destDir: 'workers'
});

return new MergeTree([app.toTree(), workers]);
```

This will basically just copy the `app/workers` directory to `dist/workers` during build, and also apply all changes and trigger the livereload.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not an immediate solution (pre-alpha), but have a look at: https://github.com/runspired/skyrocket

@ebrahim-pasbani: CORS won't help you because of the [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) same-origin policy. For a quick-and-dirty fix I used `xhr` (or `$.getScript`). See [gist](https://gist.github.com/roman01la/e7a7b879698574c45ca0).